# Nested dictionaries for word count cache

Tags: python, dictionary, caching

Apologies if this has been addressed before. I can't find any previous answers that address my specific problem, so here it is.

The exercise requires that the user inputs a .txt file name. The code takes that file, and counts the words within it, creating a dictionary of word : count pairs. If the file has already been input, and its words counted, then instead of recounting it, the program refers to the cache, where its previous counts are stored.

My problem is creating a nested dictionary of dictionaries - the cache. The following is what I have so far. At the moment, each new .txt file rewrites the dictionary, and prevents it being used as a cache.

```
def main():

file = input("Enter the file name: ")       #Takes a file input to count the words

d = {}    #open dictionary of dictionaries: a cache of word counts]

with open(file) as f:

    if f in d:      #check if this file is in cache.

        for word in sorted(d[f]):       #print the result of the word count of an old document.
            print("That file has already been assessed:\n%-12s:%5d" % (word, d[f][word]))

    else:       #count the words in this file and add the count to the cache as a nested list.

        d[f] = {}       #create a nested dictionary within 'd'.   

        for line in f:              #counts the unique words within the document.
            words = line.split()

            for word in words:
                word = word.rstrip("!'?.,")     #clean up punctuation here
                word = word.upper()             #all words to uppercase here

                if word not in d[f]:
                    d[f][word] = 1
                else:
                    d[f][word] = d[f][word] + 1

    for word in sorted(d[f]):       #print the result of the word count of a new document.
        print("%-12s:%5d" % (word, d[f][word]))


    main()      #Run code again to try new file.

main()
```

Comment: Try declaring d = {}   outside of the scope of main().

Comment: you're using f instead of file. It refers to the same variable

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help with this. Moving the d dictionary out of the function has resulted in the new dictionaries nesting properly. However, the function is unable to detect the presence of the same file being entered twice. The nested lists are prefixed with:" {<_io.TextIOWrapper name='filename.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>: " any idea how to address this? Thanks again! – grainman 49 secs ago

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix:

```
d[file] = {}
....
d[file][word] = 1  # and so on
```

because when you cahnge `f` d[f] still refers to the same entry in `d`

Also, you can reuse `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda x: defaultdict(int))

def count(file):
    with (open(file)) as f:
        if file not in d:
            # this is just list comprehension
            [d[file][word.rstrip("!'?.,").upper()] += 1 
                 for word in line.split()
                     for line  in f]
    return d[file]

def main():
    file = input("Enter the file name: ")
    count(file)
    if file in d:
        print("That file has already been assessed, blah blah")
    for word in sorted(d[file]):       #print the result of the word count of a new document.
        print("%-12s:%5d" % (word, d[f][word]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: this won't fix it - `d` is still re-initialised every time `main()` is called

Comment: what is inside that function? it is not in the code example.

Comment: @asongtoruin anyway, just updated the answer to add main()

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help with this. Moving the d dictionary out of the function has resulted in the new dictionaries nesting properly. However, the function is unable to detect the presence of the same file being entered twice. The nested lists are prefixed with:" {<_io.TextIOWrapper name='filename.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>: " any idea how to address this? Thanks again!

Comment: @grainman it is actually the first four lines of this response - please use file name as a key instead of a file handler

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you re-initialise the dictionary every time you call `main()`. You need to declare it outside the loop wherein you ask the user to provide a file name.

The process could also be neatened up a bit using `collections.Counter()` and `string.translate`:

```
from collections import Counter
import string
import os.path

d = {}

while True:
    input_file = input("Enter the file name: ")
    if not os.path.isfile(input_file):
        print('File not found, try again')
        continue

    if d.get(input_file, None):
        print('Already found, top 5 words:')
    else:
        with open(input_file, 'rb') as f:
            d[input_file] = Counter(f.read().upper().translate(None, string.punctuation).split())

    for word, freq in sorted(d[input_file].items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])[:5]:
            print(word.ljust(20) + str(freq).rjust(5))
```

This will print the top 5 most frequent words and their frequencies for a file. If it has already seen the file, it'll provide a warning as such. Example output:

```
THE                    24
OF                     15
AND                    12
A                      10
MODEL                   9
```